# django-tables2: use request user in render method

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I'm using djnago-tables2 to display data from my event model. I need to get the current request user into the render method of the table (to further call a model function to get the response of the current user).

How can i do this?

**My Model**

```
class Event(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=254)
    start=models.DateTimeField()
    end=models.DateTimeField()
    invited_user=models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)

    def getResponseFromUser(self, user):
        try:
            return Response.objects.filter(event=self, user=user).order_by('-pk')[0]
        except Exception:
            return None

class Response(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    event=models.ForeignKey(Event)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    SEEN=0
    YES=1
    PROBABLY_YES=2
    PROBABLY_NO=3
    NO=4

    RESPONSE=(
        (SEEN, _('seen but undecided')),
        (YES, _('Yes')),
        (PROBABLY_YES, _('probably yes')),
        (PROBABLY_NO, _('probably no')),
        (NO, _('No')),
    )
    response=models.IntegerField( choices=RESPONSE, default=SEEN)

    @property
    def getResponseText(self):
        return self.RESPONSE[self.response][1]
```

**Table**

```
class EventTable(tables.Table):

    requestUser=None # to be set from request (externally)

    eventResponse = tables.Column(empty_values=(), verbose_name="Response", orderable=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
        attrs = {"class": "table"}
        exclude=['id', 'user_can_invite', 'description', 'organizer']

    def render_eventResponse(self, record):
        responseObject=record.getResponseFromUser(self.requestUser)
        if not responseObject:
            return ''
        else:
            return responseObject.getResponseText
```

**View**

```
class PersonalEventTableView(SingleTableView):
    model = Event
    table_class = EventTable
    template_name = 'list_events.html'
    paginate_by = 50
```

in urls.py the view is rendered with PersonalEventTableView.as_view()

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use this plugin here: https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-crequest

Use it like this:

```
def render_eventResponse(self, record):
    from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware
    current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
    user = current_request.user
    responseObject=record.getResponseFromUser(user)
    if not responseObject:
        return ''
    else:
        return responseObject.getResponseText
```

Answer (score 6):

You could very simply add the request into the table's context.

```
class PersonalEventTableView(SingleTableView):
    model = Event
    table_class = EventTable
    template_name = 'list_events.html'
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Override SingleTableView class method """
        context = super(SingleTableMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        table = self.get_table(**self.get_table_kwargs())
        
        # add the request directly to your table
        table.request = self.request
        context[self.get_context_table_name(table)] = table
        return context
```

Which will now make it available in your Table class.

class EventTable(tables.Table):

```
eventResponse = tables.Column(empty_values=(), verbose_name="Response", orderable=False)

class Meta:
    model = Event
    attrs = {"class": "table"}
    exclude=['id', 'user_can_invite', 'description', 'organizer']

def render_eventResponse(self, record):
    # self.request.user is available
    responseObject=record.getResponseFromUser(self.request.user)
    return responseObject.getResponseText if responseObject else ""
```

Comment: This makes more sense than the accepted answer as no third party module is required.